# Как сделать надпись на TShape?

Tags: delphi, vcl

Мне необходимо сделать надпись на TShape.  У меня есть класс в полях которого есть шейп. В конструкторе класса я создаю шейп. TShape создается на панели у которой свойство `visible = false;`

```
procedure TShape.Paint;
var s : string;
begin
   inherited;
  s := inttostr(tag);
   with Canvas do
      TextOut((Width - TextWidth(s)) div 2, (Height - TextHeight(s)) div 2, s);
end;
```

Данный код не работает если visible панели =false; Почему? Какой выход может быть из сложившейся ситуации? количество экземпляров класса будет большим, по этому не хочется создавать лейбы и прочее.

Comment: Отредактировал ваш вопрос, пожалуйста проверьте и примите к сведению на будущее (оформление кода, лишние благодарности, метки)

Comment: Непонятно как Вы определили что код не работает. Шейп создается на невидимой панели.....а как Вы хотите разглядеть результат отрисовки?

Comment: У меня в конце потока вызывается  showmessage

Comment: @MashaMalevich так может Вы покажете именно тот кусок кода, который и не работает? Данная вырезка должна прекрасно работать, если её правильно использовать. В Вашем вопросе не отражено того как это используется и где.